# Highlight Rows with 2 conditions in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, highlight

I need to highlight in red the shipments that are over 4 days in-Transit and also mark in green everything that is delivered (no matter the time in transit). The rest of the data should remain white as default. I just start using Python and I need some help to figure this out.

I tried some random formulas but none of them applied to my case. So I really appreciate it if someone can assist.

Example = pd.DataFrame({'Tracking': ['1006879694', '2993851011', '7589912853','9833130823','2977450965','5811747185','9350589150','9350589161'], 'Transit Time':[12,4,2,1,6,4,1,10], 'Status':['In-Transit','In-Transit','In-Transit','In-Transit','Delivered','Delivered','Delivered','Delivered']})

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, an image is not.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391)